# Is the default CQ5 Search Configuration incorrect?

Tags: lucene, aem, jackrabbit

i need to optimize the CQ5 lucene indexing configuration for my application.

I want to provide a custom search configuration but i struggle to really understand the default configuration.

Source: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/SearchIndexingConfig.html)

**First question:**
Are the "include"-tags used in the default configuration correct?

For example:

The default configuration uses the tag "include" to include the Property "jcr:content/jcr:lastModified" for the nt:file-Aggregate

```
<aggregate primaryType="nt:file">
    <include>jcr:content</include>
    <include>jcr:content/jcr:lastModified</include>
</aggregate>
```

Compare this to the Jackrabbit wiki which uses the "include-property" for the exact same case. Source: http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/IndexingConfiguration

```
<aggregate primaryType="nt:file">
  <include>jcr:content</include>
  <include-property>jcr:content/jcr:lastModified</include-property>
</aggregate>
```

I only can assume it doesn't matter but i can't find any source to confirm this.

**Second question:** for the nodeType "cq:PageContent" all properties of four levels are aggregated.

```
<aggregate primaryType="cq:PageContent">
  <include>*</include>
  <include>*/*</include>
  <include>*/*/*</include>
  <include>*/*/*/*</include>
</aggregate>
```

I assume that because of the aggregation all properties are indexed which are contained within these 4 levels.

Or do i must consider the index rules for the nodeType nt:base which basicly only includes properties which are matching the pattern ".*:.*".

```
<index-rule nodeType="nt:base">
  <property nodeScopeIndex="false">analyticsProvider</property>
  <property nodeScopeIndex="false">analyticsSnippet</property>
  ...
  <property isRegexp="true">.*:.*</property>
</index-rule>
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default configuration is ideed incorrect as confirmed by the Adobe CQ5 Support.

For the aggegate to work correctly properties must be included by the "include-property"-Tag

So the default search configuration (or atleast the documentation) is not correct https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/SearchIndexingConfig.html)